# Tail emission in Aeon

Tags: aeon, tail-emission

Tail emission in Monero is implemented in [`cryptonote_basic_impl.cpp`](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/c9063c0b8f78a1fca4c2306d5b1df5f664c030c2/src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_basic_impl.cpp#L98), but I don't see it in Aeon's [counterpart](https://github.com/aeonix/aeon/blob/1c1efd235ed5d5d51ef62b69fc4c3db70a5d4f3b/src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_basic_impl.cpp#L61).
Will it be added to Aeon in the future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There appears to be a community consensus for an AEON tail emission based on what I have seen on [Bitcointalk](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=641696.msg12887631#msg12887631), [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Aeon/comments/4t9j6j/time_to_reach_consensus_on_tail_emission_and/) and IRC. I think most AEON users consider tail emission to be part of the [AEON roadmap](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/832/does-aeon-have-a-development-roadmap). Other users at various times have had the [false impression](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1569082.msg15771187#msg15771187) that it has already been implemented. However its implementation has not yet formalized or codified.

One proposal being considered by AEON core developer Smooth is [described](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=641696.msg12887631#msg12887631) as follows:

> Once the base reward declines below 0.3/minute, then reward will switch to inflationary at a target rate of 0.8888888....%/year (actual rate may deviate slightly in practice due to variations in block rate, block reward penalty, rounding, etc.)

The above proposal is similar but not identical to the [system used by Monero](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1516/comparison-of-monero-and-bitcoin-money-supply-and-block-reward-schedules) where the reward is set to a pace of 0.3 XMR per minute (.6XMR per block with an average block time of 2 minutes).

Answer (score 1):

Late into 2017, during the code rebase bounty discussions, contrary to the earlier coined 0.8888…% inflation rate per year, it seems there’s growing consensus to actually adopt the same tail emission rate of 0.3 AEON per minute (thus 1.2 AEON per 4-minute block), which proposal was [posted on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Aeon/comments/7mbzo6/some_clarifications_on_rebase_and_tail_reward/) by smooth_xmr.